# Integration by substitution (multiple variables)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, substitution

I want to calculate the volume of $E = \{(x,y): x,y>0, (x+y)^3 <axy \}$ where $a>0$. 
 I defined, $U= (0, \infty) \times (0, \pi/2), V=\{(x,y): x,y>0\}$  And then  $T:U \to V$ by $T(r, \theta) = (r\cos^2(\theta), r\sin^2(\theta))$.

It is easy to check that $T$ is diffeomorphism and $J_T(r, \theta) = r\sin(2\theta)$ where $J_T(r, \theta) = \det(D_T(r, \theta))$.

Also, $T^{-1}(E) = \{(r, \theta) \in U : r < a\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)\}$ Therefore, using the well-known theorem about variable-change and also Fubini's theorem, we get the following:

\begin{align}
V(E) & = \int_E 1\,dx\,dy = \int_{T^{-1}(E)} |J_T(r,\theta)|\,dr\,d\theta \\[8pt]
& = \int_{T^{-1}(E)} r\sin(2\theta) \, dr \, d\theta= \int_0^{\pi/2}\left[ \int_0^{a\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)} r \sin(2\theta)\,dr \right]\,d\theta \\[8pt]
& = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{a^2}{2}\sin(2\theta)\cos^4(\theta)\sin^4(\theta)=\frac{a^2}{32} \int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin(2\theta))^5
\end{align}

I am not really sure if what I did here is correct. Is it ok? I am not sure because the integral left to calculate is not "nice", and in the question there was a hint to use the substitution $x=r\cos^2(\theta), y = r\sin^2(\theta)$ which is what I did here, so I am wondering if what I did here is correct as the integral left is more annoying than I expected, so maybe I did something wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: The final integral is not difficult: $(\sin 2\theta)^5 = 3\sin^5\theta\cos^5\theta = 32\sin^5\theta(1-\sin^2\theta)^2\cos\theta$.

Comment: @rogerl Why is it better now? am I supposed to find the indefinite integral of this? The cosine at the end kind of "destroys" the expression, isn't it? And about everything else I did, all was correct?

Comment: $$ \int_0^{\pi/2} [ \int_0^{a\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)} r \sin(2\theta)\,dr ] \,d\theta $$
$$ \int_0^{\pi/2}\left[ \int_0^{a\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)} r \sin(2\theta)\,dr \right]\,d\theta $$ The second format above is definitely better than the first, which you had originally. Look at the MathJax code.

Comment: No, the $\cos\theta$ is just $d(\sin\theta)$.